# Regex to reject a statement having only words, but accept a statement having words and numbers

Tags: c#, regex

There is a text file like:

> My Name Is Sam
>
> My 0.22 1.65
>
> Name 2.21 2.99
>
> Is 3.31 4.12
>
> Sam 4.97 5.95

I want to reject the first statement having only words.

I want to consider the statement having words and numbers so that I can put it in an array.

How can I do this in Regex?

My code works for English, but not for characters like Chinese.

```
while ((line2 = streamReader2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // If line contains numbers and words, then split if by space and store in an array.
    if (Regex.IsMatch(line2, @"[^0-9\p{L}_ ]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) 
    {
        wordArray = line2.Split(null); //split each string by blankspace
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like code doesn't work as you describe it- for me it's match all lines. Are you sure you code work as you want?

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake. It would be  @"[^0-9\p{L}_ ]+" instead of  @"[^0-9p{L}_ ]+"

That is a "\" character between 0-9 and p{L}

Comment: *but not for characters like Chinese* Some examples, please...

Comment: Am I correct that you want to skip all lines which contain only text or you just wanna skip first line?

Comment: Try `if (line2.Any(Char.IsDigit) && line2.Any(Char.IsLetter)) { wordArray=line2.Split();  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may omit regex here and use `if (line2.Any(Char.IsDigit) && line2.Any(Char.IsLetter))`. This will only return true if the line contains both a Unicode letter and any Unicode digit.

Then, use the following fix:

```
var wordArray = new List<String[]>();               // Declare wordArray
while ((line2 = streamReader2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line2.Any(Char.IsDigit) && line2.Any(Char.IsLetter)) // If line2 contains letter and digit
        wordArray.Add(line2.Split());  // Add the line split with whitespace to wordArray
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/HKzsgk)

Comment: I kind of wanted to use an array because of Random Access.

Comment: I can store words from the wordArray2 into the database as easy as wordArray[1], wordArray2[2] etc

Comment: @DebaleenSenguptaVehere Well, that is something not related to the question already, but yes, you may access the line word arrays using indexing, too, just make sure that index is not bigger than the size of the list.